# Automatically number inequalities

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering

I have a long chain of inequalities and I would like to add some explanation for some of the steps under those inequalities. I have seen people do this like `\stackrel{(i)}{\leq}`. This is what I would like but I would like to have a counter that does this for me, so (i), (ii), and so on with an automatic increment so that I will not have to change everything if I add a line.

The biggest issue that I can think of and which I don't know how to solve is that that counter has to be reset when I use it again in a new equation (or something similar) environment. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{hints}
\renewcommand{\thehints}{\roman{hints}}
\newcommand{\hintedrel}[2][]{%
  \refstepcounter{hints}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\label{#1}\fi
  \mathrel{\overset{\mathrm{(\thehints)}}{\vphantom{\le}{#2}}}%
}
\newcommand{\restarthintedrel}{\setcounter{hints}{0}}

\begin{document}
$a\hintedrel[lab1]{\le}b\hintedrel[lab2]{<}c$

(\ref{lab1}): because it's so.

(\ref{lab2}): I tell you it is.

$\restarthintedrel a\hintedrel[lab3]{\le}b\hintedrel[lab4]{<}c$

(\ref{lab3}): because it's so.

(\ref{lab4}): I tell you it is.
\end{document}
```

The `\hintedrel` command has an optional argument, a label for referring later to the inequality.

Before a new chain of hinted inequalities you can write `\restarthintedrel` to restart from 1.

### Different implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{\restarthintedrel}
\AfterEndEnvironment{align}{\restarthintedrel}
\newcounter{hints}
\renewcommand{\thehints}{\roman{hints}}
\newcommand{\hintedrel}[2][]{%
  \stepcounter{hints}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\csxdef{hint@#1}{\thehints}\fi
  \mathrel{\overset{\textrm{(\thehints)}}{\vphantom{\le}{#2}}}%
}
\newcommand{\restarthintedrel}{\setcounter{hints}{0}}
\newcommand{\hintref}[1]{\csuse{hint@#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a\hintedrel[lab1]{\le}b\hintedrel[lab2]{<}c\overset{*}{\le}d
\end{equation}

(\hintref{lab1}): because it's so.

(\hintref{lab2}): I tell you it is.

\begin{align}
a&\hintedrel[lab3]{\le}b\\
&\hintedrel[lab4]{<}c
\end{align}

(\hintref{lab3}): because it's so.

(\hintref{lab4}): I tell you it is.
\end{document}
```

This assumes that the hints will be referred to only after they are defined (with the standard `\label`-`\ref` mechanism **amsmath** would raise an error). You have to add similar `\AfterEndEnvironment` for each math environment you use.

Comment: Thanks! I've tested it and it seems to look good, but why is it not possible to use `\stackrel`? If I look carefully I think that (i) is not really centered above the `\le`. Furthermore, would it be possible to automatically reset the counter or would that become too cumbersome?

Comment: I've added a missing pair of braces that will center the (i). The problem of resetting the counter is: when do you want to reset it? Say, for example, that a chain is split into two for typographical reasons: the numbering should continue.

Comment: I don't think that would be a problem to reset the counter if I split the chain into two because I would have explained already then what (i) and (ii) and so on mean.

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. One more question: What does `\csuse` do? I cannot find it using Google.

Comment: `\csuse` is a function defined by **etoolbox**, that builds a command name from a sequence of characters. Actually `\csuse{abc}` is equivalent to the primitive TeX construction `\csname abc\endcsname`.

Answer (score 10):

This might be what you're after, using a counter that increments at every use and resets at the start of every `\section` in your document. This can be modified, of course:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{chngcntr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr

\newcounter{numrel}% Counter for numering relations
\counterwithin*{numrel}{section}% Counter resets at every section
\newcommand{\numrel}[1]{% Relation numbering
  \stepcounter{numrel}% Increment numrel counter
  \overset{(\roman{numrel})}{#1}% Print counter + relation
}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{align*}
  P(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
       &\overset{(i)}{\leq} cx^3+dx^2+ex+f \\
       &\overset{(ii)}{<} gx^4+hx^3+ix^2+jx+k  
\end{align*}
\section{Second section}
\begin{align*}
  P(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
       &\numrel{\leq} cx^3+dx^2+ex+f \\
       &\numrel{<} gx^4+hx^3+ix^2+jx+k  
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Numbered relation using \stackrel]

In the example above, the first section uses `\overset` while the second uses the newly defined `\numrel` command, to show the similarities. It would also be possible to modify the code to accommodate for using references so that your document text will change according to the change of adding/removing a line in your equation. The [`chngcntr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) was used for more flexibility in formatting the counter resetting.

---

In order to accommodate the possibility to reference the counter within your text, here's a modified minimal example that uses the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to reset the counter at the end of the `align*` environment, as well as some `amsmath` counter manipulation using [Multiply defined labels using hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9939/multiply-defined-labels-using-hyperref/9963#9963). It uses two counters, the global counter to produce unique reference hooks (important for `hyperref`), and a local counter which is actually displayed and reset for each equation. The `\numrel{<rel>}{<lab>}` now takes two mandatory arguments. The first is the relation `<rel>` while the second is the label `<lab>` that may be referenced elsewhere:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{hyperref}% https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

\newcounter{numrellocal}% Local counter for numering relations
\renewcommand{\thenumrellocal}{\roman{numrellocal}}% Counter numrellocal uses lowercase roman numerals
\newcounter{numrelglobal}% Global counter for numering relations
\renewcommand{\thenumrelglobal}{\roman{numrellocal}}% Counter numrelglobal uses lowercase roman numerals, but results in value from numrellocal

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\numrel}[2]{% Relation numbering
  \stepcounter{numrellocal}% Increment local counter
  \refstepcounter{numrelglobal}% Increment global counter and create correct reference hook, with label-text from local counter
  \ltx@label{#2}% Label numrel counter
  \overset{(\thenumrellocal)}{#1}% Print counter + relation
}
\makeatother
\AfterEndEnvironment{align*}{\setcounter{numrellocal}{0}}% Resets numrellocal at the end of align*

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{align*}
  P(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
       &\stackrel{(i)}{\leq} cx^3+dx^2+ex+f \\
       &\stackrel{(ii)}{<} gx^4+hx^3+ix^2+jx+k  
\end{align*}
\section{Second section}
\begin{align*}
  P(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
       &\numrel{\leq}{rel1} cx^3+dx^2+ex+f \\
       &\numrel{<}{rel2} gx^4+hx^3+ix^2+jx+k  
\end{align*}
If you look at (\ref{rel1}), you will notice it is different from (\ref{rel2}).
\begin{align*}
  P(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
       &\numrel{\leq}{rel3} cx^3+dx^2+ex+f \\
       &\numrel{<}{rel4} gx^4+hx^3+ix^2+jx+k  
\end{align*}
If you look at (\ref{rel3}), you will notice it is different from (\ref{rel4}).

\end{document}
```

[image: Numbered relations with referencing capability]

Comment: Excellent! Is there a general "name" to use for equation environment like `equation`, `align` and so on or should I write a line for each environment that resets the counter after that environment? Also, how do I refer to (i) and so on? There are not really labels defined for those lines.

Comment: the "less than" in the last line isn't neatly aligned with the other two relations.  perhaps this could be fixed by applying `\clap` to the reference label; the label itself isn't wide enough to cause a problem.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing the second version so it becomes compatible with `hyperref`.

Comment: @Werner I also changed `\stackrel` into `\overset` and removed the nonsense `\ensuremath`. It should be `\overset{\textup{(\thenumrel)}}{#1}`, probably.

Comment: @egreg : I'm not sure your edit fixed all issues with hyperref. That is, the reference hooks would be `numrel.i', where i is the value of the current counter, and when it is reset it produces duplicate hooks, which means the hyperlinks always link to the first instance.  I put in an edit to fix this, by using a global counter to index the hooks, yet which when displayed yields the desired local counter.