# Incompatibility between etoolbox and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, incompatibility, etoolbox

I tried to compile Werner's second answer from [Automatically number inequalities](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29478/automatically-number-inequalities/29482#29482) with the `hyperref` package. However, the first run will give me the error below:

```
Runaway argument?
{\@firstoffive }\fi ), you will notice it is different from (\ref {re\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

While the second run does not give me any errors, but the inequality referencing doesn't work, i.e. I get ?? instead of i and ii.

If I don't include the `hyperref` package, then the code compiles fine.

For completeness, here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\newcounter{numrel}% Counter for numering relations
\renewcommand{\thenumrel}{\roman{numrel}}% Counter numrel uses lowercase roman numerals
\let\textlabel\label% Use text \label rather than math \label
\newcommand{\numrel}[2]{% Relation numbering
  \begingroup%
  \refstepcounter{numrel}% Increment numrel counter and create correct reference hook
  \textlabel{#2}\endgroup% Label numrel counter
  \ensuremath{\stackrel{(\thenumrel)}{#1}}% Print counter + relation
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{align*}{\setcounter{numrel}{0}}% Resets numrel at the end of align*

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{align*}
  P(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
       &\stackrel{(i)}{\leq} cx^3+dx^2+ex+f \\
       &\stackrel{(ii)}{<} gx^4+hx^3+ix^2+jx+k  
\end{align*}
\section{Second section}
\begin{align*}
  P(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
       &\numrel{\leq}{rel1} cx^3+dx^2+ex+f \\
       &\numrel{<}{rel2} gx^4+hx^3+ix^2+jx+k  
\end{align*}
If you look at (\ref{rel1}), you will notice it is different from (\ref{rel2}).
\begin{align*}
  P(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
       &\numrel{\leq}{rel3} cx^3+dx^2+ex+f \\
       &\numrel{<}{rel4} gx^4+hx^3+ix^2+jx+k  
\end{align*}
If you look at (\ref{rel3}), you will notice it is different from (\ref{rel4}).

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `etoolbox`, but rather in the managing of labels by `align` and the other alignment environments of `amsmath`.

What you want is to avoid using `\label` as redefined by `amsmath` inside `align`, which is already available as `\ltx@label`; since you also reset the counter, it's necessary to use a `hyperref` trick in order to have correct links: defining and stepping a `Hnumrel` counter is what's needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{numrel}% Counter for numering relations
\newcounter{Hnumrel}% Keep hyperref happy and don't duplicate anchors
\renewcommand{\thenumrel}{\roman{numrel}}% Counter numrel uses lowercase roman numerals

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\numrel}[2]{% Relation numbering
  \refstepcounter{numrel}% Increment numrel counter and create correct reference hook
  \stepcounter{Hnumrel}%
  \ifmeasuring@\else\ltx@label{#2}\fi % Label numrel counter (issue only once)
  \overset{\text{(\thenumrel)}}{#1}% Print counter + relation
}
\makeatother
\AfterEndEnvironment{align*}{\setcounter{numrel}{0}}% Resets numrel at the end of align*

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\begin{align*}
  P(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
       &\numrel{\leq}{rel1} cx^3+dx^2+ex+f \\
       &\numrel{<}{rel2} gx^4+hx^3+ix^2+jx+k  
\end{align*}
If you look at (\ref{rel1}), you will notice it is different from (\ref{rel2}).
\begin{align*}
  P(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
       &\numrel{\leq}{rel3} cx^3+dx^2+ex+f \\
       &\numrel{<}{rel4} gx^4+hx^3+ix^2+jx+k  
\end{align*}
If you look at (\ref{rel3}), you will notice it is different from (\ref{rel4}).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works! I can guess from your solution that `hyperref` automatically associates the counter `numref` with the counter `Hnumref`. Is that correct? Is there something I can read to find out more about how this works?

Comment: @ILiketoCode If the control sequence `\theHfoo` exists when `hyperref` has to make a link associated to the counter `foo`, then it uses `\theHfoo` rather than `\thefoo`; this can be exploited to get unique internal references. The manual of `hyperref` explains the trick.

Answer (score 13):

A lot of `hyperref` stuff is loaded a the start of the document. Our code compile on my system if I make this change to it

```
\AtBeginDocument{\let\textlabel\label}%
```

Then it seem to get the proper textual `\label` stored.

Comment: Indeed, putting this code just before the `\begin{document}` solves the problem for me.

Comment: Actually you could just have moved `\let\textlabel...` after `\begin{document}`, but this code almost does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! @egreg's answer is admirably thorough, but this was a lot simpler.

Comment: I added your solution [to the Latex Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Problems_with_Links_and_Equations_2), @daleif. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Alas, this doesn't change anything for me. Adding the `hyperref` package produces these errors despite adding the `label` redefinition.