# amsmath - multiple labels in one equation

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, amsmath

I would like to use multiple labels in the same equation when using `amsmath`. Basic latex already has this feature, but not amsmath, which seems to manipulate labels in complicated ways. Is it possible to alter the `amsmath.sty` code to restore this feature?

Or, alternatively, how to temporarily unload the `amsmath` package? This issue arises when compiling together different articles with `\include`, some using `amsmath` and not others. But I found that unloading packages is not possible in latex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use backticks, ` `, to "highlight" words and other items that are TeX instructions or filenames. I've done so in your posting.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "labels"? Do you want to assign multiple `\label{...}` commands to one equation, or do you want more than one "tag" (equation number, etc) to show up next to the object of interest? The `amsmath` package provides the command `\tag{...}`, which lets users create fairly elaborate tags.

Comment: I want to assign multiple \label{...} commands to one equation. I use one label to number the equation, and other labels to number the parameters appearing in it (I use stepcounter, etc..). Labels are used to refer to those parameters (I use ~100 parameters). I would prefer not to alter my document, because I already wrote it without amsmath, but now I need to compile it with another document that uses amsmath...

Comment: Have a look at the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9939/multiply-defined-labels-using-hyperref and the answer that Martin Scharrer provided.

Comment: thank you, but contrary to this guy, my labels are inside each individual equation, not inside a pre-determined command. maybe I should do the whole thing manually.

Comment: I suggest you post a MWE (minimum working example) of your code, containing maybe two equations and the various `\label` commands you're trying to make compatible with `amsmath`. Without such a MWE, it's very difficult (impossible?) to figure out what's going one and what may have to be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

According to p. 86 of the `cleveref` user guide,

> With **amsmath**, the original `\label` command is stored in `\ltx@label`, and `\label@in@display` replaces `\label` inside [single-line] equations. `\label@in@display` just saves the label for later, and defining it is left until the end of the equation, when `\ltx@label` is finally called.

Hence, you may want to include the following code in the preamble, *after* loading the `amsmath` package:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ltxxlabel\ltx@label
\makeatother
```

so that you have a command that doesn't contain the "secret letter" `@`. Alternatively, you could execute the command `\let\ltxxlabel\label` *before* loading the `amsmath` package. Then, replace all `\label` commands in your document -- *except*, of course, those that are actually associated with equation numbers -- with `\ltxxlabel`.

I cannot try out this suggested solution myself since I don't have a clear idea as to how you use the `\label` command in your document for purposes *other* than creating associations with equation numbers. Nevertheless, I would encourage you to try out this method.

---

*Addendum*: The `cleveref` user guide has the following to say about the treatment of the `\label` macro in the *multiline equation environments* (such as `gather`, `align`, and `multline`) of the `amsmath` environment:

> The `amsmath` multi-line equation environments scan their bodies twice: Once to measure, once to typeset. In the measure phase, the `\label`  command is disabled by letting it to `\@gobble`. ... Unfortunately, `amsmath` wasn't designed with redefinitions of `\label` in mind ... The `multline` environment works a bit differently to the other `amsmath` environments, in that `\label` is *disabled* during the typesetting phase, and *enabled* during the measuring phase.

Given these observations, it would seem that only the adventurous and daring may want to delve into redefining the ways that `amsmath` works with the `\label` command in its multiline equation environments. I must admit to not being sufficiently daring, at least not in this category...

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}\label{foobar}
y &= x \tag{foo}\\
y &= x \tag*{[bar]}\\
y &= x \tag{baz}\\
y &= x \label{foobarbaz}
\end{align}

See Equation~\ref{foobar} and \ref{foobarbaz}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, but it does not exactly reply to what I want: I would prefer not to alter my document, because I already wrote it without amsmath, but now I need to compile it with another document that uses amsmath...I use \label in combination with \stepcounter,\incr... to number the parameters inside the equation.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is because [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align` environment actually collects or gather the entire contents before typesetting it for horizontal alignment purposes. At least one way around this would be to reverse your thinking, and therefore *reference* the parameters in the equation and *label* them within your text. This way there is no conflict in labelling an entry twice within `align`.

Here is a minimal example that illustrates this concept:

[image: Referencing parameters in amsmath's align environment]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcounter{parms} \renewcommand{\theparms}{[\arabic{parms}]}
\newcommand{\newparm}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{parms}\arabic{parms}\label{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  y &= ax^2+bx+c \label{eq1}\\
  z &= i_{\ref{eq-i}}+j_{\ref{eq-j}}+k_{\ref{eq-k}} \label{eq2}
\end{align}
See~\eqref{eq1} and~\eqref{eq2}.
Specifically,~\eqref{eq2} has parameters~\newparm{eq-i},~\newparm{eq-j} and~\newparm{eq-k}.
\end{document}
```

The command `\newparm{<label>}` defines the labelling of a parameter (using `\refstepcounter`). It also prints the parameters number and then labels it as `<label>`. The display of the parameter is set by `\theparms` where `parms` is the parameter counter. All this can be modified.