# Using \label with amsmath nested environments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cross-referencing, amsmath

First of all, I'm not sure these environments are supposed to be nested, but the fact is the alignment comes out exactly how I wanted, and no errors are issued.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\begin{align}
a &= b + c \notag \\
%\label{important}
b - a &= -c \\
c - a &= -b
\end{align} \\
a - (b-a) - (c-a) = 2a
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem appears when I uncomment the `\label`, then compilation is interrupted with:

```
! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'important' will be lost.
```

The result is still OK, and I wouldn't mind too much if I didn't have to press enter every time I compile...

I could bypass `amsmath`'s redefinition of `\label` as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40185/15647), but is there another possible fix? Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clearly this is a bug, and will be investigated as such.

but here's another horrible hack that merely gives the nasty warning that

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `important' multiply defined.
```

at least you wouldn't have to press enter every time ...

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{align}
a &= b + c \tag*{} \\
b - a &= -c
\label{important} \\
c - a &= -b
\end{align}\\
a - (b-a) - (c-a) = 2a
\end{gather}
some text with an xref: \eqref{important}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `align` inside `gather` is officially supported (see p. 23 of `amsldoc.pdf`, the end of section 10.2). However, using `\label` inside the inner `align` is buggy: if `\notag` is used, then the error is raised, if `\notag` is not used, a label in the second line is duplicated.

A horrible hack is to disable the error generation:

```
\makeatletter
\def\label@in@display{\gdef\df@label}
\makeatother
```

This of course will suppress the error also when it's legitimately raised, so use with care.

Comment: For me this horrible hack is the only thing that worked, using `\tag*{}` instead of `\notag` did not change anything in the generated errors. I use tETA2 style from Taylor & Francis, not article - maybe that is the reason.

Comment: @peschü Impossible to say without seeing the style, but I'm not surprised that an in-house style has compatibility problems.

Answer (score 1):

As @egreg [points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60573/2417), you can run into trouble if you nest the `align` environment in this way (despite the fact that it is supported). There is a variant called `aligned` that works inside other display math environments but this doesn't number the individual equations.

In your case I would be inclined to simplify matters by putting the last equation in its own environment, reducing the spacing between this and the `align` environment, and not using `gather` at all.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\bgroup %Grouping restores \belowdisplayskip after use
\setlength\belowdisplayskip\jot
\begin{align}
a &= b + c \notag \\    
\label{important}
b - a &= -c \\
c - a &= -b
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
a - (b-a) - (c-a) = 2a
\end{equation}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: But `aligned` does not give a number for each equation, it treats the whole block as a single equation instead (which is useful in other cases).

Comment: @Jellby --- I have edited my answer.

Comment: At the end of section 10.2 of the documentation it's explicitly mentioned that `align` *can* be used inside `gather`.

Comment: @egreg --- Right as always! I'll edit my answer later.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `\notag` command, which instructs `amsmath` not to put a `tag` (in this case, a number) by the equation- hence, labelling it doesn't make any sense which is why you get the error.

If you want to `\label` that first equation, you'll need to remove the `\notag` from the first line. If you don't want to `\label` it, then the `\notag` is fine.

Comment: `\notag` is in the first line; the `\label` is in the second line.

Comment: @IanThompson the `\label` wants to apply itself to the most recent `<thing>` which in this case is the first line. the `\label` works on the most *recent* thing, not on the *next* thing

Comment: Try it for yourself with a simple example.

Comment: @IanThompson already have. perhaps I have misunderstood the issue

Answer (score 0):

Although it does not seem to be your problem here, this bug can also occur because of two `\notag` commands in the same line. Putting the `\notag` twice in the same line is useless and may seem innocuous, but it generates the aforementioned bug.