# Avoiding extra vertical space between groups of equation environments

Tags: spacing, align

I need to write a long list of numbered equations. I know that I could use the environments gather or align, but either with the gather environment I cannot have any alignment or with the align environment I should have a point of alignment which is good for all my equations, which is not the case.

For example, let us say that I have four equations, and I would like to align the equal signs of equations (1) and (2) and the two equal signs of equations (3) and (4). But I **do not want** to align the equal signs of equation (2) and (3). Now if I write two align environments with two equations each, the vertical space between equation (2) and equation (3) is bigger than the vertical space between equations (1)-(2) and (3)-(4). How can I avoid this and get coherent vertical spacing? Or alternatively, is there a more clever way to align a long list of equations with different aligning points?

Comment: Could you show an example?

Answer (score 7):

Is something like that you want?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
   \begin{align}
      a  &  = b + c \\
      d &  = e + f
\end{align} \\
   \begin{align}
        (b + c)³   &  = b³  + 3b² c + 3bc²  + c³  \\
        (e + f)³   &  =  e³   + 3e² f + 3ef²  + f³ 
      \end{align}  
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks! It was indeed easy... I was convinced that it was not allowed to nest gather and align environments.

Comment: Me too… until I tried since there seemed to be no other simple solution.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite work. If you add \label{} to all four equations, then amsmath gives an error "Multiple \label's". I think because inside the gather* environment you can't have more than one \label.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. See also [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60566/using-label-with-amsmath-nested-environments)

Comment: @antonio: I confess I didn't think of checking whether there was a problem with the labels.  Mybe a hack with `subequations` and the way it is numbered would help?