# Put tags over several parts of an equation, that are consistent with eq numbering and can be referenced in text

Tags: equations, tags, overbrace

Is it possible to put a tag (and a corresponding label) for a part of an equation over a brace, and another tag for a different part of the same equation over another brace?
Something like this:
[image]

The tag(label) numbering should continue the numbering of the equation counter, and should be referenced later in the text.

I'm sorry if this was already answered, but I haven't managed to find such a question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: searching on this site will show you many similar questions ... and what you tray so far? `\overbrace{q+b}^{(1)}` is your friend. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132526/overbrace-with-square-bracket and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics

Comment: @Zarko I think OP wants the equation label (for `\ref` purposes, for example) to also be in the overbrace.

Comment: @Troy, maybe, but I didn't recognise this in her/his question. A MWE would be very helpful for clarify the question. to have two tags in one equation? this is not so simple. if this is the case, than OP should reformulate question and I should return deleted tags.

Comment: Thank you @Zarko, I know about \overbrace but I wanted to ask about adding a tag (an equation number) with a corresponding label, so that I can reference it later in text (as Troy says).

Comment: This seems mildly relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40216/117534. You can try combining it with `\overbrace` like Zarko says. Do you need the overbraced tags to have the same counter as your other equations?

Comment: where are tags is not so relevant, main problem is to have two tags in one equation. if you will reformulate your question title in this sense, then you will see, that your question is close/duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148592/can-i-define-more-than-one-label-inside-an-equation-environment?

Comment: @Troy thank you, the solution you posted is very interesting. I would like the tags to have the same counter as my other equations, but if it is not possible, your proposed solution might work. I didn't realize that I could reference labels that I define later in the document.

Comment: @Zarko, the solutions in the question you posted are only about having multiple labels, but they all point to the same tag (for example to (1)). But if I understand well other answers, it's not possible to have multiple equation tags and a label for each tag in equation environment.

Comment: multiple labels are the main problem. without them you can not referenced the tags. and multiple labels in standard `amsmath` aren't allowed.

Comment: @tex_newbee -- please add to your question the information that you would like these labels to (1) use the same counter as your other equation labels, and (2) be referenceable elsewhere in your document.  if i had time to experiment (which i don't), i would try this: set a hyperref anchor for each, use `\stepcounter` with the usual equation counter, and `\tagform` to format it in a `\[...\]` or `equatino*` environment.  i'd assume basing this on `amsmath`, and would have to dig into the `amsmath` code for details.

Comment: I used Troy's suggestion, with some modifications so that prior to using the new counter I change it's value with the value of the equation counter.