# How can one refer to a part of an equation?

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, lists

When having multiple equations inside one displaymath environment, it is sometimes desirable to refer to just one of them without having to break the environment up into smaller pieces. Take for example the following set of boundary conditions (where the last three labels won't work, but are written here to illustrate the goal of this question):

```
\[\left\{\begin{array}{l l l l}
    (i)\label{eq:i}\quad        & \epsilon_1E_1^\perp=\epsilon_2E_2^\perp,\quad     &
    (ii)\label{eq:ii}\quad      & B_1^\perp=B_2^\perp,\\\\
    (iii)\label{eq:iii}\quad    & \mathbf{E}_1^\parallel=\mathbf{E}_2^\parallel,\quad   &
    (iv)\label{eq:iv}\quad      & \dfrac{1}{\mu_1}\mathbf{B}_1^\parallel=\dfrac{1}{\mu_2}\mathbf{B}_2^\parallel.
\end{array}\right.\]
```

[image]

How can one refer to any of the above four equations separately? Is a list inside a math environment perhaps possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is one way: create your own `\mylabel`, that mimics the regular `\label`. The following is a [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)-compatible version:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,hyperref}

\providecommand{\phantomsection}{}% In case hyperref is not loaded
\AtBeginDocument{\let\textlabel\label}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9939/5764
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]{\raisebox{.7\normalbaselineskip}{\phantomsection}#1%
  \def\@currentlabel{#1}\textlabel{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  \left\{\begin{array}{l l l l}
    \mylabel{\text{(\textit{i})}}{eq:i}\quad        & \epsilon_1E_1^\perp=\epsilon_2E_2^\perp,\quad     &
    \mylabel{\text{(\textit{ii})}}{eq:ii}\quad      & B_1^\perp=B_2^\perp,\\\\
    \mylabel{\text{(\textit{iii})}}{eq:iii}\quad    & \mathbf{E}_1^\parallel=\mathbf{E}_2^\parallel,\quad   &
    \mylabel{\text{(\textit{iv})}}{eq:iv}\quad      & \dfrac{1}{\mu_1}\mathbf{B}_1^\parallel=\dfrac{1}{\mu_2}\mathbf{B}_2^\parallel.
  \end{array}\right.
\]
See~\ref{eq:i}, or~\ref{eq:iv}, or~\ref{eq:iii}, or~\ref{eq:ii}.
\end{document}
```

`\mylabel{<to-print>}{<label>}` prints and stores `<to-print>` in the `<label>` that you can reference later.

Comment: `\textit` should add the italic correction by itself.

Comment: @egreg: I see. There's some checking in the background going on.

Comment: As I use hyperref in pretty much all my documents, I'll give this question a shot: do you know a way around the error "File ended while scanning use of \Hy@setref@link"?

Comment: @Betohaku: I've updated the answer to provide a [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)-compatible version.

Comment: I was trying to find a solution that worked with `hyperref` but yours works with and without. +1

Comment: Somehow the clickable refs make the view go about the height of an equation too low, any idea why this is?

Comment: @Betohaku: I've raised the link by 70% of `\normalbaselineskip`.

Comment: @Werner Beautiful solution. I'll use a full \normalbaselineskip myself, I find it is just a bit more comfortable to read.

Answer (score 4):

This one is based on Werner's idea but works only when `hyperref` is loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]{%
  \phantomsection#1%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
    \def\label@name{#2}%
    \label@hook
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \string\newlabel{#2}{%
        {#1}%
        {\thepage}%
        {\@currentlabelname}%
        {\@currentHref}{}%
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}%

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\[
  \left\{\begin{array}{l l l l}
    \mylabel{(\textit{i})}{eq:i}\quad        & \epsilon_1E_1^\perp=\epsilon_2E_2^\perp,\quad     &
    \mylabel{(\textit{ii})}{eq:ii}\quad      & B_1^\perp=B_2^\perp,\\\\
    \mylabel{(\textit{iii})}{eq:iii}\quad    & \mathbf{E}_1^\parallel=\mathbf{E}_2^\parallel,\quad   &
    \mylabel{(\textit{iv})}{eq:iv}\quad      & \dfrac{1}{\mu_1}\mathbf{B}_1^\parallel=\dfrac{1}{\mu_2}\mathbf{B}_2^\parallel.
  \end{array}\right.
\]
See~\ref{eq:i}, or~\ref{eq:iv}, or~\ref{eq:iii}, or~\ref{eq:ii}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]