# Own equation environment for - R syntax formulas

Tags: equations, environments, r

I'd like to be able to write down formulas in R syntax as equations, i.e. I'd like to do something like this:

```
\begin{requation}
time ~ (poly(I(1/nprocs), 2) + poly(ndoms, 2) + poly(nDOF, 2))^3
\end{requation}
```

while the equation would be **numbered together with ordinary equations** and its content would be the simple text with `\texttt{}`. So, I need no math-mode inside the environment.

Do you know, how to do it?

---

#### EDIT

I've tried something like this

```
\newenvironment{requation}
{%
\VerbatimEnvironment
\begin{Verbatim}
}
{
\end{Verbatim}
\refstepcounter{equation}\hfill(\theequation)}
```

The only problem is, that in this case there is a newline after `\end{Verbatim}` which I don't want - is there any possibility to get rid of it?

Comment: This has been asked before, eg: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161674/15036

Comment: The simplest way to do that might be just to use ordinary `equation` environments, and mark the R code with `\verb|...|`.

Comment: @Thruston I'm not interested in just numbering verbatims. I want to use them the same way as equation, including the common numbering for both of them. I.e. if I have 3 equations, then I want my requation to have number 4 and following equation to have number 5.

Comment: @Thruston And yes, your advice with `verb` is exactly, what I'm looking for. Could you, please, expand your comment into an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to get what you want without defining a new environment, or using any extra packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\verb"time ~ (poly(I(1/nprocs), 2) + poly(ndoms, 2) + poly(nDOF, 2))^3"
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

[image: an equation with verbatim tt text]

Notice that the equation number has been pushed to the line below; that's because the R code you gave as an example is rather long, and the default text width is not that wide.

You could avoid typing the `\verb` bit if you use the `shortvrb` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortvrb}\MakeShortVerb{"}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
"time ~ (poly(I(1/nprocs), 2) + poly(ndoms, 2) + poly(nDOF, 2))^3"
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

but that would have an effect on the rest of your document, and you might struggle to find a short verb character that is not part of R syntax.  The advantage of the first solution is that you can change the character each time, as required:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\verb|time ~ (poly(I(1/nprocs), 2) + poly(ndoms, 2) + poly(nDOF, 2))^3|
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

In all cases, the verbatim bit must be all on one line.

Comment: Hi, when you have a bit of your time can you see my question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561798/photon-without-arrows-using-feynmp-auto Thank you very much.