# How to associate a symbol to a list

Tags: cross-referencing, itemize

I'd like to associate a symbol to an `\itemize` environnement so that when I use`\ref` it prints the symbol. I'd also like to have the symbol chosen printed in the middle of the `\itemize` environnement. It kind of looks like a `\tag` in the `\equation` environnement but I get compilation error when I tried it...

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref, nameref, cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize} \tag{$\dagger$} \label{épée}

\item blalabla
\item blablabla
\item blablabla
\end{itemize}

blablabla cf \cref{épée}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? That will make it easier for us to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Werner's fine answer at [How can one refer to a part of an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160466/how-can-one-refer-to-a-part-of-an-equation), I can make it work with `hyperref`, but not with `cref`.  Perhaps someone who know the guts of `cref` can adapt (here, I just `\let` `\cref` to `\ref`).

The new environment is `myitemize`, and it takes an optional argument, in which the label can be specified with `\ilabel`.  Of course, you must define all the associated symbols with your environment in advance, as you will see in my preamble.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\let\cref\ref
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\csname mysym1\endcsname{\dag}
\expandafter\def\csname mysym2\endcsname{\ddag}
\expandafter\def\csname mysym3\endcsname{*}
\expandafter\def\csname mysym4\endcsname{\&}    
\newcounter{itnum}
\newenvironment{myitemize}[1][]%
  {\relax\par\stepcounter{itnum}#1\hfil[\csname mysym\theitnum\endcsname]\hfil\itemize}%
  {\enditemize\ignorespaces}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\i@label\label}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9939/5764
\newcommand{\ilabel}[1]{\def\@currentlabel{\csname mysym\theitnum\endcsname}\i@label{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]

\begin{myitemize}[\ilabel{épée}]
\item blalabla
\item blablabla
\item blablabla
\end{myitemize}
\lipsum[4]
blablabla cf \cref{épée}
\begin{myitemize}[\ilabel{ref2}]
\item blalabla
\item blablabla
\item blablabla
\end{myitemize}
\lipsum[4]
blablabla cf \cref{ref2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To help the novice user learn a bit more about what is done, I am expanding the explanation.

`\makeatletter...\makeatother` - See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do).  Basically, `@` is a restricted character in user code, but its use in macro names can be enabled/disabled with these two commands.  Since much of the TeX core and packages use this `@` character in their macro names, the enabling must be done to allow modifications to those routines.

`\expandafter\def\csname mysym1\endcsname` - numbers are not allowed in macro names when using `\def`, so `\def\mysym1{\dag}` will not work, but that is what I want to achieve.  The name `\csname mysym1\endcsname` is effectively equivalent to a `\mysym1` syntax.  However, saying `\def\csname...` would redefine `\csname`, which I don't want to do, and so `\expandafter` says "skip over the next thing (in this case `\def`) and expand what follows, namely `\csname`.  It effectively is equivalent to the disallowed `\def\mysym1{}`, but follows the rules.

`\newcounter{itnum}` and `\stepcounter{itnum}` - creates (zeroes) and increments a LaTeX structure called a "counter", which is just an integer index.  The current value can be accessed (as a text string) by placing `\the` before the counter name, in this case `\theitnum`.

`\par` - start a new paragraph

`\relax` - do nothing, but it doesn't "expand", and so something trying to expand the code leading up to it will stop expanding when it get to `\relax`.  I put it here, so that nothing which followed could accidentally be taken as part of the optional argument.

`\hfil` is stretchable glue (`\hfill` is a stretchier version of `\hfil`).  It can stretch its horizontal length between the items to its left and right.  Think of it as a rubber band.

`\@currentlabel` and `\i@label` are the way LaTeX refers internally to a label, and how it creates a new one.  It is the first of these command that I must modify to make this method work.  Then I must call on the second of these, passing it the "new" label definition.

`\AtBeginDocument{}` - Says "don't do this until `\begin{document}`.  The reason for this is that `hyperref` is busy redefining stuff all over the place, and so I don't want to do this until `hyperref` is fully done doing what initializations it wants to do.

`\ilabel` - Since a user can't use `@` characters in their code normally, I create this macro to effectively invoke `\i@label` with the properly redefined label.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry but it has only been two weeks since I started using Latex so I'm affraid I didn't get any of your code...It seems a bit too complicated for me (maybe too soon). Maybe you know an easier solution (using a different environnement?). Anyway thank you a lot for your answer I guess it took you some time to figure it out!

Comment: @WrabbitW I understand you are learning, but it in this case, you don't yet have to fully digest it.  You can copy the code in the preamble, between the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` directly into your own document preamble.  Thereafter, you can mimic the usage that I had in the document itself.  The only additions you will need to make to my preamble code are adding more lines of the form `\expandafter\def\csname mysym4\endcsname{\&}`, where the number `4` becomes `5`, and the 5th symbol is added instead of `\&`.  The `lipsum` stuff is just filler text.  `cref` could remain an issue...

Comment: @WrabbitW  Even if you still use `cref`, you could use this simultaneously, as long as you referred to the labels with `\ref` instead of `\cref`.  Also, if you are using `\cref`, eliminate the `\let\cref\ref` line, which merely forced the letters `\cref` to call upon `\ref` instead.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot but I don't want to use something I don't understand... and there's too many commands I don't know about... I guess I'll just label the middle line of my `\itemize` (because in your code the dagger symbol appears on top of the list and I wanted it to be in the middle...) Sorry for bein a pain in the @@@..

Comment: @WrabbitW I will edit my answer to provide a more detailed explanation, to help you learn.

Comment: @WrabbitW Please see revision.

Comment: Thank you for this complete explanation of your code. I think I understood almost all of it, but I don't exactly get what `\hfil`does... It does comlicate a lot the issue to have a different symbol in each new `\itemize`! So I will try to write something omiting this part, but tomorow cause it's getting late and i'm getting tired! Thanks again.

Comment: @WrabbitW I made a different symbol for each `myitemize`, otherwise if two such calls used the same symbol, then referring to the symbol would be ambiguous as to which `myitemize` you wanted.  I also realized that both fills can be changed to `\hfil` (but not both to `\hfill`).  These commands don't print.  Think of them as rubber bands attached to each margin, and whatever is between them (the label) gets suspended midway across the line, regardless of how long the line is.  That is how TeX centers things automatically...with what is called "glue" and what I am calling a rubber band.

Comment: Ok so if I put the command `\hfil[\csname mysym\theitnum\endcsname]\hfil` after the `\begin{itemize}` I should get the symbol inside the environement right?

Comment: Well it's not really working but I think I'll just do it like this. A last issue remains : when clicking on the internal link it leads me to the previous page (which is the first page of the subsection) and not to the list...

Comment: Also I don't quite well get the point of using `\newcounter{i@counter}` because it doesn't appear after... Neither I get the line that follows where you define `\ilabel`

Comment: @WrabbitW  The `i@counter` appears to be extraneous.  I guess I overlooked deleting it.