# Is it posible to have different tags in the text linking to one label?

Tags: cross-referencing, tags

When I write parameterized or otherwise indexed equations I often would like to be able to refer to `eqn:f_i` (i.e. producing a clickable link in the document) using:

- the given tag `$f_i$` for general discussion
- a custom tag like `$f_1$` when referring to 'specializations

The first requirement is easily fulfilled by `\ref{eqn:f_i}`, how about the second one?

```
%MWE
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Today we're going to talk about parameterized functions.
Consider the different alternatives \ref{eqn:a_i}:
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:a_i}
  a_0(x) = 42, \qquad a_1(x) = sin(x), ...
\end{equation}
These are used by the well known function \ref{eqn:f_i}:
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:f_i}
  f(x) = a_i \tag{$f_i$}
\end{equation}
Surprisingly $f_0$ % I can write this but it doesn't link to the \label{eqn:f_i}
is constant while $f_1$ % same here...
strangely resembles a trigonometric function I've heard about in school.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question (i.e., the 2nd requirement).  Could you expand your example to include a full minimum working example showing what you hope to achieve?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: There you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Werner's approach from [How can one refer to a part of an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160466/how-can-one-refer-to-a-part-of-an-equation).  After adding his pixie dust (slightly modified) to the preamble, then I make these added calls in the cited equation:  `\instancelabel{f_0}{eqn:f_0}\instancelabel{f_1}{eqn:f_1}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath,refcount,lipsum}

\AtBeginDocument{\let\textlabel\label}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9939/5764
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\instancelabel}[2]{\def\@currentlabel{$#1$}\textlabel{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Today we're going to talk about parameterized functions.
Consider the different alternatives \ref{eqn:a_i}:
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:a_i}
  a_0(x) = 42, \qquad a_1(x) = sin(x), ...
\end{equation}
These are used by the well known function \ref{eqn:f_i}:
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:f_i}\instancelabel{f_0}{eqn:f_0}\instancelabel{f_1}{eqn:f_1}
  f(x) = a_i \tag{$f_i$}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1-2]

Surprisingly \ref{eqn:f_0} % I can write this but it doesn't link to the \label{eqn:f_i}
is constant while \ref{eqn:f_1} % same here...
strangely resembles a trigonometric function I've heard about in school.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @mrclng I removed the part of Werner's definition referring to `\phantomsection`.  However, this question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44088/when-do-i-need-to-invoke-phantomsection, indicates I might have been too hasty.  If you experience problems in the behavior of the macro, let me know and I will revise accordingly.

Comment: However, the second answer at that same question indicates we are OK with the current arrangement.  Namely, "The `\phantomsection` command is needed to create a link to a place in the document that is *not* a figure, equation, table, section, subsection, chapter, etc."  Since we are an equation, all should be good.